# CakePHP 2.1 conditional statements in view.ctp

Tags: conditional-statements, cakephp-2.1

Can anyone please help with this. For some or other reason the `!empty()` in view.ctp does not seem to work.

I have 4 records where 'occupation' has text and another 2 records where there is nothing at all. If I use `!empty()` as below they all disappear and if I use `empty()` they all come back. What am I doing wrong?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php if (!empty($shoulderExamination['occupation'])):?>
    <dt><?php echo __('Occupation'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($shoulderExamination['ShoulderExamination']['occupation']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`if (!empty($shoulderExamination['ShoulderExamination']['occupation']))`

instead of

`if (!empty($shoulderExamination['occupation']))`